# Warning: Illegal string offset - php

Tags: php

**Code**

```
$chandet = channeldetails(12567);
print_r($chandet);
foreach ((array) $chandet as $det) {
    echo $det . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($det);
    // exibit 1 for this print-r output
    foreach ((array) $det['videos'] as $ails) {
        foreach ((array) $ails as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

i am getting this error `Warning:  Illegal string offset 'videos'`

and i can not seem how to fix it i've tried to use a numeric value such as `$det[0]` but it still does not work It seem that all my code is correct i have research but didn't find anything i am using print_r to see if there are any infractions in the array but there are non.

excbit 1  : Array
(

```
[videos] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [channel_video_id] => 3433
                [channel_id] => 342333
                [video] => pathtofile/something.mp4
                [start] => 0
                [length] => -1
                [sort_order] => 0
                [is_ad] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [channel_video_id] => 2364
                [channel_id] => 342333
                [video] => pathtofile/something.mp4
                [start] => 0
                [length] => -1
                [sort_order] => 1
                [is_ad] => 0
            )

    )

      )
```

1st print_r results

```
Array
(
    [channel] => Array
        (
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [channel_id] => 3434
                    [cdn_id] => 343
                    [channel_name] => testing
                    [server_ip] => 93.167.671.93
                    [app] => testing-chorigin
                    [app_inst] => live
                    [stream] => testing
                    [repeat] => 1
                    [metadata] => 0
                    [scheduled] => 2018-02-20 10:40:00
                    [last_modified] => 2018-02-20 22:40:00
                    [active] => 1
                    [show_video_names] => 0
                    [overlay_message] => 
                    [closed_on] => 
                    [reason] => 
                )

            [videos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [channel_video_id] => 344
                            [channel_id] => 344
                            [video] => myvid
                            [start] => 0
                            [length] => -1
                            [sort_order] => 0
                            [is_ad] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [channel_video_id] => 324
                            [channel_id] => 344
                            [video] => myvid
                            [start] => 0
                            [length] => -1
                            [sort_order] => 1
                            [is_ad] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => success
    [message] => channel Found
)
```

Thank You

Comment: Your first loop should be `foreach ($chandet['videos'] as $values) {`

Comment: Is the last part the output of the first or the print_r inside the foreach?

Comment: ok i will try this please give me a few mins

Comment: this is the second print_r output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update efter edited question:

```
echo 'Printing data <br />' . PHP_EOL;
echo $chandet['status'] . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
echo $chandet['message'] . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;


foreach( $chandet['channel']['details'] as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach( $chandet['channel']['videos'] as $video) {
  foreach( $video as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this loops out the data but i still get invaild arguent supplied for foreach

Comment: can you print the data of `var_export( $chandet );`?

Comment: array (
     'videos' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'channel_video_id' => '233',
        'channel_id' => '233',
        'video' => 'myvid',
        'start' => '0',
        'length' => '-1',
        'sort_order' => '0'      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'channel_video_id' => '233',
        'channel_id' => '233',
        'video' => 'myvid',
        'start' => '0',
        'length' => '-1',
        'sort_order' => '1'      ),
    ),
  ),
  'status' => 'success',
  'message' => 'channel Found',
)

Comment: That's not valid. You must have missed something.

Comment: i have posted full thing in my question @niclas

Comment: Printing data 

success

channel Found



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yourphot/public_html/scaleengine/sceduling.php on line 309



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yourphot/public_html/scaleengine/sceduling.php on line 313



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yourphot/public_html/scaleengine/sceduling.php on line 309



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yourphot/public_html/scaleengine/sceduling.php on line 313

Comment: that is what is returned

Comment: i fixed those errors by adding (array) after foreach(

Comment: Great, no problem :)